# MongoDB search in multi dimensional arrays for value in specific position

Tags: arrays, mongodb, search, position, wildcard

Given this, three MongoDB objects

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "array" : [
        [ "a1", "b1" ],
        [ "a2", "b2" ]
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "array" : [
        [ "a1", "b2" ],
        [ "a2", "b1" ]
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : 3,
    "array" : [
        [ "b1", "a1" ],
        [ "b2", "a2" ]
    ]
}
```

How to find the all Documents that have the value "b1" in array in position 1 of one or more nested arrays?

As example:

If I search for "b1" in position 1 of the nested arrays, I expect to get document 1 and 2 but not 3.

If I search for "b1" in position 0 of the nested arrays, I expect to get document 3 and not 1 or 2.

I was hoping for some kind of wildcard like "array.*.1":"b1"

Comment: Do you mean something like [`db.collection.find({"array": {"$elemMatch": {0: "b1"}}})`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tfPyqk7agE3) and/or  [`db.collection.find({"array": {"$elemMatch": {1: "b1"}}})`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lXY-S1B3m97)?

Comment: No, that search is not deep enough. I don't want to find the element in array, but inside the arrays that are contained in array.

Comment: Did you try the links?

Comment: I tried on my db and mistyped something. I'm an idiot :(. The links work fine.

Comment: First, I have to read a little more MongoDB documentation, I obviously missed essential information on my first run. :)

Answer (score 1):

As shown by @rickhg12hs, the solution lies in the usage of $elemMatch (https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/).

This allows you to specify the desired contents of a field (by name OR by index) inside the items of an array.

If the item is a json Object you can specify the field name to contain a specific value and if it's an array you can simply specify the index.

In my case, the solution is:

```
db.collection.find({
  "array": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "0": "b1"
    }
  }
})
```

With "0" being the index inside the nested array and "b1" the desired value.

I case of nested JSON Object, simply replace "0" by the desired field name.
Fun fact. If the field name happens to be "0" than you can mix arrays and objects and get results for both.